# Disabling cookies

Tags: facebook, cookies

I disabled all the cookies in my browser. And, then I got an error when I tried to login into facebook. How common is it for a user to disable all cookies ? I was trying to test my application. Is  this is a valid use case ?

Answer (score 1):

Many people consider cookies a privacy violation and block them by default (especially so-called "third-party" cookies typically used by advertising networks).

Having said that cookies are pretty much essential for any type of login or session control (like shopping carts) so if you need them then use them. Your users can always turn them back on if they want.

The main thing is you should at least attempt to check the user has cookies enabled when they require them and inform them that they will not be able to log in or use that particular feature.

As a general rule cookies are enabled in browsers by default. If a user has turned them off then chances are good they will know how to turn them back on (on unblock your site) when necessary.